# Trapped In A Well (Beginner)

Tags: science

You ironically fall into the well, with no way to get out. You, of course try digging out from under, but only to find that a Tungsten plate is below, all you have is a rope, a rock, and one liquid of any choice. What will you do? (The lid is sealed shut and you can't climb out)

Comment: How long is the rope?

Comment: as long as you need it to be :P

Comment: How much of the liquid do we receive?

Comment: as much as you need

Comment: What is the lid made out of?

Comment: the lid is made out of tungsten

Comment: MOLTOV COCKTAIL

Comment: ;D you have me dying of laughter, but remember, you only have the rope, water, and any liquid of your choice

Comment: Note how it doesn't say "how can you get out?" It says "what will you do?" So I would take about 500ml of cyanide, my chosen liquid, and drink it. Better quick death than long and drawn out... ;)

Comment: @quintec x)) really?

Comment: Can the liquid be essence of Houdini?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a liquid, I'd take

> 30% hydrogen peroxide, as this will dissolve the tungsten just fine.
>  Provided I'm still alive after that,

I'd use the stone to

> crumble the tungsten oxide, since I have no clue how aggressive that stuff is to skin.

And with the rope I'd

> knot a hangman's noose before I start, just in case in all my chemical ignorance I'll produce a living hell by pouring hydrogen peroxide on a tungsten plate in such a confined space.

Well, I'd probably ponder somewhat more on the problem before trying the luck of the clueless. But let's say that's what I'd do. Please enlighten me about what fate I've chosen for the virtual well dwelling me.

Comment: Cyanide still seems like a safer option... :P

Comment: @Quintec: I totally agree. :-) And I'd prefer it over the rope anytime.

Comment: @Ilikescience: If that's the answer, could you enlighten me a bit? Would that really work, all things considered? No buildup of toxic gases, no problems with heat, just works? If so, what did you have in mind for the rope? Somehow I don't think I suggested exactly what you intended.

Comment: It was all a distraction, technically in most cases it would be useless

Answer (score 2):

1. Wrap one end of the rope around the stone,
2. then immerse the stone in some adhesive like mseal or feviquick or something that could stick stone to other material
3. then throw the stone outside the well and wait for sometime till it sticks to something,
4. then climb the well using rope

I am not sure if this will work, but suggestions are welcome